# Matplotlib - plotting nested categories along categorical x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Picture's worth a thousand words]

I have a dataset as above, with nested categories inside of major x axis labels. A and B could represent, say, different stores. I want to be able to, for a single x-axis point, have a sub-cluster of A and B categories, as indicated by the black bars in the image.

```
data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
plt.scatter(data, len(data))
```

This gives an x/y unqeual size ValueError. Wondering if there's a way to achieve this.